# How to display an image on two devices?

Tags: android, image, mobile

I want to implement a kind of feature like copying an image file from one device to another. During the image transferring, I need to update the UI simultaneously on both side. For example, the image flies out of the device A, and then flies into the device B. On the user's side, he/she just see that image moves from one screen to another screen, then the transfer is completed.

One possible way I'm thinking so far is to display an animation during the image transferring. But I don't know how to display an image partially on screen A, and partially on screen B. Hope someone could give me some hints. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to find the time difference between the two devices.

I wrote an app that performed synchronized playback of an audio file on multiple devices.  To synchronize the devices, I had them ping a time server and make note of how much the device's clock differed from the server's clock.  With this offset value, I was able to do a reasonably good job of synchronizing the playback.  I'm glossing over a lot of the details (latency, variability, leap second, etc.), but this was the basic idea.

To synchronize the UI on both devices, the two devices need to know the difference between each other's clock.  Once you have this value, you simply time the animation appropriately.  I've only ever done it with a server, but if the two devices are talking to each other for the file transfer, perhaps you could have one device ask the other for its time and compute the offset.

Tip: compute the difference several times, then use standard deviation to select a good value.  If you want to really study how this is done, check out how NTP does it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think this is a kind of solution if the animation is same on both sides. But what I'm thinking is a little bit different than that. I hope to use the image which is being transferred to draw the animation. For example, if the image has 20% transferred, I hope to draw 80% on device A, and 20% on device B. So the whole action just looks like that image flies from A to B. I wonder is this possible? Or what kinds of techniques would be involved?

Comment: Any synchronized action between the devices requires, well, synchronization.  If you find a way to do your animation that doesn't require synchronization, please post it.  I'd be curious to hear how you solve the problem.